# UIView subclass draws background despite completely empty drawRect: - why?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview

So, I have a custom UIView subclass which enables drawing of rounded edges. The thing draws perfectly, however the background always fills the whole bounds, despite clipping to a path first. The border also draws *above* the rectangular background, despite the fact that I draw the border in drawRect: before the background. So I removed the whole content of drawRect:, which is now virtually empty - nevertheless the background gets drawn!

Anybody an explanation for this? I set the backgroundColor in Interface Builder. Thanks!

Comment: It's likely a problem with your drawing code.  Can you post it so we can take a look?  My guess is that somewhere you're drawing in a way that either ignores alpha values or draws something opaque over what you thought you drew out.  Also, just to make sure, when you set the `backgroundColor` you have the alpha set appropriately?

Comment: Well, I can post my drawRect:, but as I said, it's completely empty:
<pre>
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
}
</pre>
The alpha is set in IB, and it get's drawn to whatever color I set it, with whatever alpha.  
I assume there must something interior be going on, however there is no new superview and no subview that could be drawing the background. Also the backgroundColor of the view's layer is nil.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry for this monologue. :)

The thing is that the UIView's layer apparently draws the background, which is independent from `drawRect:`. This is why you can't get rid of the background by overriding `drawRect:`.

You can either override `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` and make the layer draw whatever you want, or you override `- (void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)newColor` and don't assign *newColor* to *backgroundColor*, but to your own ivar, like *myBackgroundColor*. You can then use *myBackgroundColor* in drawRect; to draw the background however you like.

---

Overriding `setBackgroundColor:`

Define an instance variable to hold your background color, e.g. *myBackgroundColor*. In your init methods, set the real background color to be the clearColor:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super init...])) {
        [super setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Override:

```
- (void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)newColor
{
    if (newColor != myBackgroundColor) {
        [myBackgroundColor release];
        myBackgroundColor = [newColor retain];
    }
}
```

Then use *myBackgroundColor* in your drawRect: method. This way you can use the color assigned from Interface Builder (or Xcode4) in your code.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an easier fix:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Yes, that's what's accomplished by overriding setBackgroundColor:. I was more wondering why anything was drawn at all, despite drawRect: being empty. Answer was that the background is drawn in drawLayer:inContext:.

Answer (score 6):

I hesitate to suggest this because I don't want to offend you, but have you set opaque to NO?

Comment: No offense taken, the question is actually a good one: Yes, opaque was set to NO. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is easily reproducible:

Create a new View-Based iPhone Application. Create an UIView subclass and leave the drawRect: method completely empty. In Interface Builder, drag a UIView into the main view, assign it a background color and set the class of the view to your subclass. Save, build and run, and see, the view shows the background color.

I have circumvented this behaviour by overriding setBackgroundColor: and assigning the color to my own ivar, always leaving the backgroundColor property nil. This works, however I'm still wondering why this works this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO
```

It's that simple.

From the [UIView Reference Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/clearsContextBeforeDrawing)

Oops.  I misunderstood the question.  The OP (original poster) wants their custom control to support the standard "backgroundColor" property (eg, set by the gui designer), but does NOT want the system to paint that color. The OP wants to paint the bg himself so that he can round the corners.

In that case, the post about overriding the layer level drawing is correct.

The solution I posted will prevent the UI system from clearing your buffer before drawing.  When you have no bg defined, if clearsContextBeforeDrawing is set, the iOS will clear your view's buffer, setting all pixels to transparent black.  Doing this for a full-screen view takes about 5ms in an iPad3, so it's not free (pushing that 2048x1536 pixels never is).  For comparison drawing a full-screen bitmap (using kCGBlendModeCopy to force blitting) takes ~25ms (using quartz, not GPU).

Comment: This doesn't prevent the backgroundColor being drawn; at least not im my quick test.

Comment: What happens if you unset backgroundColor?

Comment: Then it works, which is why I chose to override `setBackgroundColor:` to set no color on super and save the background color to my own ivar. This way the background color assigned in interface builder gets used in my custom `drawRect:` and I don't have to handle this in code. :)

Comment: oh, I see.  Your custom control wants to support the standard "backgroundColor" property, but does NOT want the system to paint that color.  You want to paint the bg yourself so that you can round the corners.  Sorry, that wasn't clear at first.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to override the code that copies the background colour into the view's layer, I'm not a fan of this approach. I believe it can cause issues with views intended to be opaque. My suggestion is to create a custom colour variable like this:

```
@IBInspectable var foregroundColor: UIColor = .black {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}
```

Now, set your view's `backgroundColor` to clear and use `foregroundColor` in your drawing code in its place. The code above takes care of updating it when the value changes, and also exposes it to Interface Builder if required.

Another alternative is to use your view's `tintColor` instead, and to ensure that it updates correctly when tint colour changes. You may be reserving tint colour for other uses though, so this is not necessarily ideal. If you use `tintColor`, don't forget to include the following:

```
override func tintColorDidChange() {
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```