# How do I override -drawLayer:inContext: to make my UIView draw a transparent background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, cgcontext

From the answer to the question [UIView subclass draws background despite completely empty drawRect: - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554200/4422704) I have learned that I can override `-drawLayer:inContext:` for my custom `UIView` to make it not draw a background in it's `backgroundColor` before I can draw it.

I am making a view that displays a rating, like iTunes, and I want the view's `backgroundColor` to be the color of the unselected stars, and the `tintColor` the color of the selected stars, like this:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    CGFloat starWidth = self.bounds.size.width / _maxRating;
    CGFloat starHeight = self.bounds.size.height;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.1f);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.backgroundColor.CGColor);
    for (int i = floorf(_rating); i < _maxRating; i++)
        [self drawStarInContext:ctx inRect:CGRectMake(starWidth * i, 0, starWidth, starHeight)];
    CGContextClipToRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, starWidth * _rating, starHeight));
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.tintColor.CGColor);
    for (int i = 0; i <= _rating; i++)
        [self drawStarInContext:ctx inRect:CGRectMake(starWidth * i, 0, starWidth, starHeight)];
}
```

This first calculates how big the stars have to be, fills with `[UIColor clearColor]` and then draws any deselected Stars and on top of that the selected Stars. This works perfectly, except for the fact that I get a background in `self.backgroundColor`. The superview I want to use this on uses an image as it's background and thus I really need it to be transparent, simply filling it with `[UIColor whiteColor]` will not do.

Please tell me what [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148335/pascal) meant.